# Embedding a document - MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm a front-end iOS dev and Mongoose is new to me. I'm trying to embed a parent category into sub category document. Here's the obj-c data model:

```
@interface CategorySub : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (nonatomic) NSString* objectId;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic) CategoryMain* categoryMain;

@end
```

Here's the Mongoose `CategorySub` schema def:

```
var CategorySubSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  _category_main : { type: String, ref: 'CategoryMain' }
},
{
  collection: 'categories_sub'
}
)
```

And the `CategoryMain` schema which is just a name for now:

```
var CategoryMainSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String }
},
{
  collection: 'categories_main'
}
)
```

And here's the relevant `create` code:

```
 CategorySub.create({
        name : req.body.name,
        _category_main : req.body.category_main._id
 }, function(err, data){
```

What I get in MongoUI for one of the `CategorySub` documents is this:
[image]

How do I change the schema def and/or the `create` call code to embed `category_main` in the `CategorySub` document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your create code is only saving the _id and is using dbref as oppose to subdocuments. This is the reason you are only getting the id and not the entire subdocument.

```
CategorySubSchema
.findOne({ name: 'YOUR NAME' })
.populate('_category_main') // <--
.exec(function (err, subdata) {
 if (err)
      console.log('The creator is %s', subdata.name);
 })
```

Please look here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/populate.html

There's another way which is to use subdocuments. In your case, it would look something like this.:

```
var CategoryMainSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    subCategories: [CategorySubSchema]
});
```

In the creation case, you will need to do the following:

```
var categoryMain = new CategoryMainSchema({name: "sub doc", subCategories:     [your  sub document] });
```

Please see the doc here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

I hope that helps.

Comment: Gotcha. So embedding uses `subdocs` vs referencing just uses `ids`, correct?

Comment: yes, I believe they each have pros and cons. It will serve what you need. Pros and cons really depends on your application. If you want to have fast read, I believe subdocs will be faster. However, if you want to ever query the sub documents by itself, you can do the dbref ID way.

Comment: And if you happen to have the time... I had another simple issue come up with cross-referencing schemas... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486766/missingschemaerror-schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model

Comment: I will just comment here as I can't make a comment on that one because I don't have enough reputation. It looks like you don't have CategorySubSchema defined yet. Is that defined somewhere else in another file?

Comment: I updated my question. I do have everything defined elsewhere, I'm just having trouble connecting everything.